# Kafka Producer Client API can not asynchronous sending when the target broker using SASL/PLAIN

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I had a simple demo to transfer data from one kafka cluster which did not use SASL to another kafka cluster which did use SASL/PLAIN. and the codes look like this:

```
 Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.50.20:9092");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);


        Properties producerProps = new Properties();
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.100:9092");
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        producerProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
        producerProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format(
                PlainLoginModule.class.getName() + " required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";",
                "admin",
                "admin"
        ));
       //and some other producer properties

        KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("test", record.key()
                            ,record.value());
                    producer.send(record);
                }
            }
```

It was just simply consuming the data and producing those data to another kafka cluster,but the thing is:
 when I wrote another consumer client to consume those data from `192.168.1.100:9092`

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.100:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");

        String password = EncryptUtil.encryptPassword(USER_NAME, QUERY_KEY, QUERY_SECRET);
        System.out.println(password);
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format(
                PlainLoginModule.class.getName() + " required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";",
                "admin",
                "admin"
        ));
        while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = 
                consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                   System.out.println(record.value());
                }
            }
```

and it had nothing to print but

```
    9419 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.1.100:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
18456 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
18456 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] (Re-)joining group
18471 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Successfully joined group with generation 21
18471 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Setting newly assigned partitions [flink-kafka-0]
27522 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Resetting offset for partition flink-kafka-0 to offset 0.
27537 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Node 0 sent an invalid full fetch response with extra=(flink-kafka-0, response=(
57556 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
87563 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
117585 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
146158 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Node 0 sent an invalid full fetch response with extra=(flink-kafka-0, response=(
176263 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
206333 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
236418 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
266492 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | group-snKiBQ0O] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
296558 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
317372 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | group-snKiBQ0O] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Group coordinator 192.168.1.100:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
326571 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=snKiBQ0O, groupId=group-snKiBQ0O] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
```

and then I was using this shell `./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.100:9092 --command-config config/client_plain.properties --group group-snKiBQ0O` to check wether the data was sent correctly and the `LOG-END-OFFSET` has a value of 5912 but the `CURRENT-OFFSET` was always 0.

At last, I changed `producer.send(record);` to `producer.send(record).get();` and the consumer client was successfully received the data. why is that? Why broker using SASL/PLAIN can not asynchronous sending data?Is there a good way to deal with it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE: I deleted all kafka log and zookeeper data,and it can work fine.But still don't understand why this happend**